# Show information from infowindow in second activity

Tags: android

I'm working in a project but I have a problem. I need to show the information like `marker.getTitle` and `marker.getSnippet`, in another activity when I click the infowindow.

When I click infowindow I can see the other layout but when I use code like

in the `MainActivity` I send the information according me jaja

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent i = new Intent (bar.this, detail.class);
    i.putExtra("title", marker.getTitle());
    i.putExtra("snippet", marker.getSnippet());
    startActivity(i);
}
```

and in the other activity I receive this information.

```
String tit = getIntent().getStringExtra("title");
tv1.setText(tit);
```

but when I execute the app and try to open this layout the app crashes

Comment: use Bundle b=getIntent().getExtra();  and b.getString("title");

Comment: post your logcat.

Comment: would be great if you will post your logcat

Answer (score -1):

ex-:first forward your logcat
below code send and get data through Intent 
1-:send data from current activity to MainActivity3

```
 Intent i = new Intent(activity, MainActivity3.class);
        i.putExtra("firstName", "Abc");
        i.putExtra("lastName", "Xyz");
        startActivity(i);`
```

`
2-:get Data

```
 Intent i=getIntent();
    String firstName=i.getStringExtra("firstName");
    String lastName=i.getStringExtra("lastName");
    dumy_text.setText(firstName+" "+lastName+" the boss ");`
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, your method is right and now the app run good :D